# Combine two 2D Datasets in single bi-dimensional histogram matrix with shared scale

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, histogram2d

I have two datasets `d1,d2` filled with 2D Data of different scale.

```
import numpy as np
d1 = np.random.normal(-30,20,(500,2))
d2 = np.random.normal(-40,10,(500,2))
```

Furthermore I am able to create separate `100 x 100` 2D Histograms (=gray scale images) from each individual dataset.

```
bins = [100,100]
h1 = np.histogram2d(d1[:,0], d1[:,1], bins)[0]
h2 = np.histogram2d(d2[:,0], d2[:,1], bins)[0]
```

but with this solution each 2D Histogram gets centered around its own mean and when plotting both histograms on top of each other they appear distributed around the same center which is in fact not true.

What I want to get is a single `100 x 100 x 2` historgam Matrix (comparable to a 2 Channel Image), which takes into account the different scales of the data so the displacement is not lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass `histogram2d` a value `bins=[100, 100]`, you are asking it to automatically calculate 100 bins in each dimension. You can do this yourself, so these two

```py
bins = [
    np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100),
    np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 100)
]
h1 = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins)
```

and

```py
bins = [100, 100]
h1 = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins)
```

are equivalent.

Knowing that, we can now calculate the bin range for both arrays combined, and use  those

```py
bins = [
    np.linspace(
        min(d1[:, 0].min(), d2[:, 0].min()),
        max(d1[:, 0].max(), d2[:, 0].max()),
        100
    ),
    np.linspace(
        min(d1[:, 1].min(), d2[:, 1].min()),
        max(d1[:, 1].max(), d2[:, 1].max()),
        100
    )
]
h1 = np.histogram2d(d1[:,0], d1[:,1], bins)
h2 = np.histogram2d(d2[:,0], d2[:,1], bins)
```

or stack the two datasets together and simplify the code a bit

```py
d = np.stack((d1, d2))

bins = [
    np.linspace(d[..., 0].min(), d[..., 0].max(), 100),
    np.linspace(d[..., 1].min(), d[..., 1].max(), 100),
]

h1 = np.histogram2d(d[0, :, 0], d[0, :, 1], bins)
h2 = np.histogram2d(d[1, :, 0], d[1, :, 1], bins)
```